# Can I install games obtained via Steam in Origin?

Tags: steam, origin

Origin seems to recognise that I purchased NFS: Hot Pursuit on Steam, and is now giving me the option to download it. Is there a way, or is it possible, to install games in Origin that have been backed-up/downloaded via Steam?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. If Origin is giving you the option to download it, won't you be able to install it once it's downloaded?

Comment: @MatthewRead, I imagine the problem is that redownloading would be prohibitively expensive or take a very long time.

Comment: Just because I am curious, is there a reason you would rather play this on Origin rather than Steam?

Comment: hmm... when I typed in my steam keys on origin, it was able to find the game from the steam folder, I didn't have to redownload any of them.  Granted NFS is not one of the titles I have, but I did not have to redownload Dragon Age Origins.

Comment: You're also working from the assumption that EA has any interest in making Origin something useful as opposed to a way to lock their customers into their own distribution platform. Becoming decently interoperable with Steam would not advance the latter.

Answer (score 5):

*I haven't installed Origin yet*, but I would say it isn't even technically possible, short of reversing the game, Steamworks and the Origin interface.

Steam and Origin are different DRM systems with easily different interfaces between the game and the distribution system (i.e. ways for the program to ask "what's the user's avatar?", "does the user own this game?", "does the user have this DLC?", "please unlock this achievement", "please begin the purchase of this hat", etc.)

[image: olololol software engineering is simple]

You can't just swap steamapp.dll for origindrm.dll (or whatever the relevant libraries are) and expect the program to work still.

The games could even be available in different versions between the two different platforms, so even just copy pasting the bulk of the game (levels, music, etc.) might be in vain.

In short, no, it's not possible.

Comment: That's a very bold claim.

Comment: @kotekzot A claim I hope I've sufficiently backed up with facts.

Comment: I'm afraid you haven't, but don't feel discouraged, as it is impossible to prove a negative in this case. I'll grant you that it is **improbable**, but never impossible.

Comment: @kotekzot I said impossible _"short of reversing the game, Steamworks and the Origin interface."_ Because that's exactly the kind of work you need to do to port a system from one set of API to another - change your system's code (what code?) to interface with the new API (how does it work?) from the old API (how did it work?). It's conceptually no different than porting from the PS3 to the Wii.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware that you revised your answer. The new version is certainly closer to being correct, though I am almost certain it is possible to avoid redownloading most of the game, as resources would generally be the same for Steam or Origin.

Comment: An impressive graphic, though it is accurate in ways you may not have intended. Notice how small the non-matching pieces are? One could easily make a patch that only changed those pieces, or, if Origin is smart enough, it could simply download the pieces that don't match, while retaining the ones that do.

Comment: @kotekzot Yes, if the software's well made the contact surface is small... but the game is also heavily obfuscated, and so is the library, and there's no documentation... good luck!

Comment: One doesn't need luck or documentation, only a fast CPU and some time, to make a delta patch; unless the resources (the bulk of the game) are different for the two versions, which I find unlikely. You're thinking about the problem in an entirely wrong key, a patch doesn't need to change the intricate functionality, it only needs to change the data, and functionality will be changed accordingly. It is a trivial matter to find the delta of two versions of a game and make a program that will apply that delta to either version.

Comment: This is not a simple as it seems, whether or not you can do this may be game specific from what I've experienced linking stuff from steam to origin.

Comment: @kotekzot You assume every single copy of the game from a distribution venue is identical, which they aren't due to DRM: any application of a general-purpose diff would produce unusable collection of garbage data. You could get a usable delta patch for personal use if you purchased a copy from each distribution venue and created a diff from those, but that would defeat the point of this whole exercise.

Comment: No, @MarkTrapp, I do not assume they are identical, I assume the bulk of the data is identical or slightly different, which the case for most games. The overwhelming majority of games are released unencrypted, and only a few relatively small files are different by vendor, depending on DRM. Your claim that a delta would be unusable is entirely unfounded, I suggest you do some research on delta patches. As you may have noticed, Origin is giving copies of the game to the people who have it on Steam, so no additional purchase is necessary. Any interested person could make the patch, if they wanted

Comment: [Please take this to chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2527/delta-patches)

Answer (score 3):

The [Origin Code Redemption FAQ](http://help.ea.com/article/origin-code-redemption-faq) lists a number of titles that can be re-redeemed through Origin. *Need For Speed: Hot Pursuit* is one of them, you'll be unsurprised to know. There's no information on what happens to the Steam version of the game, though. I actually asked that question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54630/what-happens-if-i-add-a-steam-game-to-origin) but strangely enough it was closed as a duplicate of this question :/

Comment: Nothing changes, you can use both installations in parallel as well, just make sure to use the same EA/Origin account on both.

Comment: @Mario good to know, thanks. Where were you when my question was closed? :P

Answer (score -2):

It is technically possible, but a solution does not appear to have been developed, and it is unlikely that it ever will.

There exist a multitude of ways in which conversion may be achieved, reverse-engineering the protection of Origin and Steam being one of the most complex. A delta patch would made by somebody in posession of both copies would do the trick and be fairly small, but the chances of somebody taking interest are slim.

It is highly probable, however, that the bulk of the files for both version will be the same, and there may be a way to make Origin recognize them and redownload the files that do not much, but as somebody how neither uses Origin nor has the game in question, I am unable to test this.

Comment: I'd really like to know what sort of source one is expected to provide for a negative. Unless, of course, the source request is regarding the "technically possible" bit, in which case I'd like to note that it is technically possible to find 10 numbers which, when multiplied and written down as binary, will produce an archive containing the correct Origin backup files.

Comment: The notice is regarding the "technical possible" part.

Comment: @JuanManuel well, it is technically possible. One could devise a process by which Steam backup files were turned into Origin backup files, simply because both are data. It is possible to arrive at any arbitrary data from an arbitrary seed with a clever-enough algorithm. [Russell's teapot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell's_teapot) is also technically possible, and one would have to be a fool or a god to assert that the teapot has no possibility of existence.

Comment: I think the objection is that your answer implies that such a solution is likely to be developed at some time.  Even if that wasn't your intent, I think that is why people consider it misleading.  It would be better to state that not only does it not exist now, but it would require knowledge of both proprietary systems, and neither vendor would benefit from creating it, making it extremely unlikely to ever exist.

Comment: @bwarner, you may be right, I will revise the answer, thanks. Although I must point out that it would be trivial for somebody in posession of both versions of the game to make a delta patch that would successfully make one out of the other, and it would likely be under 50MB.