# What happens if I add a Steam game to Origin?

Tags: steam, origin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing in games Origin already obtained via Steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51203/installing-in-games-origin-already-obtained-via-steam)

Now that I've installed Origin, I have the option of registering some of my other EA games (Dead Space 1 & 2, etc) on it. These are games that I've bought and already activated on Steam.

So what exactly happens if I re-register them on Origin?

- Do they get 'copied' across, so I can play them from either service?
- Do they get 'moved' across, so they are no longer accessible from Steam?

  - If this is the case, are save games compatible? (I'm guessing they are...)
- What about Steam achievements? I hope they're not removed/disabled with the game. Is this even possible (i.e. are there EA games with Steam achievements?)?

Comment: The CD code is probably one use per platform and I doubt the platforms talk to eachother. You'd have to launch the game from Steam to get STeam Achievements, it's part of the game code.

Comment: I saw that question but didn't think it was a duplicate. That one was asking *is it possible* to install the games. I'm asking about the specifics of *what happens* - i.e. whether they're then unavailable on Steam. They're not the same.

Comment: I've registered Dead Space 2 (bought on steam) in Origin, and so far, no problems at all, not even in multiplayer ...

Comment: @JeroenBaert Thanks for the useful info. I'm not going to rock the boat, but I still claim this isn't a duplicate question :P

Comment: In my opinion, it isn't a duplicate question indeed - this question asks if there are any consequences - maybe merge questions?